# How to catch sqlite3.open() errors in Lua

Tags: sqlite, lua

According to the docs (http://luasqlite.luaforge.net/lsqlite3.html#sqlite3.open)

> In case of an error, the function returns nil, an error code and an
>   error message.

But I always get the same results no matter if I provide a valid or invalid SQLite file. In fact, if I provide an inexistent file or an invalid path I still get the same results. For example:

```lua
db, code, msg = sqlite3.open("foo")) 
print(db)   -- sqlite database (0x7f9ab1628598)
print(code) -- nil
print(msg)  -- nil
```

How can I catch these errors?

Comment: The docs you've cited say that  `sqlite3.open` "opens (or creates if it does not exist)". If you want to generate an error, try `sqlite3.open("/foo")` if you're running some kind of Unix. This should give you a `permission denied` error.

Comment: Not using sqlite3 module but have you tried the basic protected call like [`pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pcall) or `xpcall` ?

Comment: @lhf As it turns out you are right. I was creating sqlite files all over the place without knowing it. Also the "invalid" path I thought I was passing turned out to be quite valid (oops). So if you want, just go ahead and enter this as your answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3.open` creates a file if it does not exist. So, providing an inexistent file is not an error.

Providing an invalid path should be an error. Calling `sqlite3.open("/foo/bar")` will probably give you an error.

Another kind of error is a permission error. Calling `sqlite3.open("/foo")` if you're running some kind of Unix should give you a `permission denied` error.